# Facebook Graph Posting Comment as User

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am building a social accounts management application and having a problem with posting comments. Currently i am able to list them all but the current version of API 2.10 is unable to post comments as user and can only post with page token. 
But the version 2.9 offers posting comments as user. In the graph explorer when I set API version to 2.9 i am able to post a comment but not in my application. I am sure that API version used in my application is 2.9 but i still get an error that graph doesn't support posting comments as user.
Am i doing something wrong or no matter which API version i use i will always get an error? I am using PHP if it matters.

Comment: are you just "sure" or do you "know"? you can just take a look at the app settings to find out if you can still use v2.9 in your app. i would not do it though, why build something on a deprecated api?

Comment: @luschn I am sure and am i using 2.9 in the app but seems that my app automatically bumped API to the 2.10 version and states that this is the oldest version that can be used. So commenting with user is not possible right now

Comment: then use v2.9 in your api calls, by adding the version tag to the api path. but again: why build something on a deprecated api?

Comment: Yeah it is deprecated but app largely depends on this feature and client needs it. I am using the 2.9 in my calls but app settings do not allow this. It is automatically bumped to 2.10 version since it is considered the oldest version.